# Alert wont display with location

Tags: javascript, php

im trying to get error codes to generate with JS so that i dont have to use die. Im using the location function to refresh the page then create the alert but it wont display. It goes as follows:

```
header("Location: register.php");   
$fields = "You did not complete all the required fields. Please try again.";         
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$fields');</script>";
```

Comment: you want to redirect to a new url or pop up an alert on the current, because you cant do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header("Location: register.php");
```

You instructed a location change before any outputs. Outputs will always be ignored in this case.

You may use:

```
header("Refresh: 10;url=register.php")
```